# Filter a list of Map by date to get all the data two weeks before now in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a list of maps as below. I want to get the maps with date two weeks before now.

NOTE
(I have reduced the number of maps in the list so that it wont be long but enough to potray
the structure of the map),

```dart
List<dynamic> allAlerts = [
    {
        "id": 4037,
        "type": "Scouting",
        "createdBy": "Algorithm",
        "message": "In the firstfield1 section there may be possible pests: Spider mite (Avocado red mite, Oligonychus yothersi), Avocado moth (Avocado Stenoma catenifer), Thrips (Greenhouse thrips, Heliothrips haemorrhoidalis), Persea mite (Oligonychus perseae), Monalonion velezangeli (Monalonion velezangeli), Whitefly (Paraleyrodes sp.), Thrips (Western flower thrips: Frankliniella Occidentalis), Thrips (Avocado thrips, Scirtothrips perseae)",
        "date": "2022-08-25T13:49:18.404932",
        "fieldId": 206
    },
    {
        "id": 4036,
        "type": "Scouting",
        "createdBy": "Algorithm",
        "message": "In the firstfield1 section there may be possible pests: Spider mite (Avocado red mite, Oligonychus yothersi), Avocado moth (Avocado Stenoma catenifer), Thrips (Greenhouse thrips, Heliothrips haemorrhoidalis), Persea mite (Oligonychus perseae), Monalonion velezangeli (Monalonion velezangeli), Whitefly (Paraleyrodes sp.), Thrips (Western flower thrips: Frankliniella Occidentalis), Thrips (Avocado thrips, Scirtothrips perseae)",
        "date": "2022-08-18T13:49:18.404932",
        "fieldId": 206
    },
    {
        "id": 4035,
        "type": "Scouting",
        "createdBy": "Algorithm",
        "message": "In the firstfield1 section there may be possible pests: Spider mite (Avocado red mite, Oligonychus yothersi), Avocado moth (Avocado Stenoma catenifer), Thrips (Greenhouse thrips, Heliothrips haemorrhoidalis), Persea mite (Oligonychus perseae), Monalonion velezangeli (Monalonion velezangeli), Whitefly (Paraleyrodes sp.), Thrips (Western flower thrips: Frankliniella Occidentalis), Thrips (Avocado thrips, Scirtothrips perseae)",
        "date": "2022-08-12T13:49:18.404932",
        "fieldId": 206
    },
    {
        "id": 4034,
        "type": "Scouting",
        "createdBy": "Algorithm",
        "message": "In the firstfield1 section there may be possible pests: Leafminer (Coffee leafminer - Perileucoptera coffeella), Spider mite (Carmine spider mite (Tetranychus cinnabarinus)), Fruit fly - Anastrepha  (Anastrepha spp.), Spider mite (Avocado red mite, Oligonychus yothersi)",
        "date": "2022-08-25T13:49:18.404932",
        "fieldId": 206
    },
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the methods *isAfter()*, *isBefore()* or *isAtSameMomentAs()* from DateTime.

Other alternative, use compareTo(DateTime other), as in the docs:

> Compares this DateTime object to [other], returning zero if the values
> are equal.
>
> Returns a negative value if this DateTime [isBefore] [other]. It
> returns 0 if it [isAtSameMomentAs] [other], and returns a positive
> value otherwise (when this [isAfter] [other]).

Here a code example of sorting dates:

```
void main() {
  var list = [
    DateTime.now().add(Duration(const Duration(days: 3))),
    DateTime.now().add(Duration(const Duration(days: 2))),
    DateTime.now(),
    DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(const Duration(days: 1))
  ];

  list.sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b));
  print(list);
}
```

With subtract, you can get the exact date that you need, for example:

```
 DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(const Duration(days: 14)))
```

And then, you can compare your dates from list with this one with methods *isAfter()*, *isBefore()* or *isAtSameMomentAs()* from *DateTime*.

God to know:

There is also Jiffy package that is used for parsing, manipulating, querying and formatting dates.

More info on this link:
https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime.parse`/`DateTime.tryParse` to parse the `date` entry for each `Map`, and filter your list by comparing those `DateTime`s to your desired time period.

> I want to get the maps with date two weeks before now.

Assuming that you mean that you want all `Map`s with a `date` value *within* the past two weeks (and nothing in the future):

```dart
var now = DateTime.now();
var twoWeeksAgo = now.subtract(const Duration(days: 14));
var filtered = allAlerts.where((map) {
  var date = DateTime.tryParse(map['date'] ?? '');
  return date != null &&
      date.compareTo(twoWeeksAgo) >= 0 &&
      date.compareTo(now) <= 0;
}).toList();
```

[`package:basics`](https://pub.dev/packages/basics) provides extensions on `DateTime` to make the comparisons more readable (and less error-prone):

```dart
  return date != null && date >= twoWeeksAgo && date <= now;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the alerts older than two months by filtering the data using `where()` filter. Inside the filter, you can check if the date is `twoWeeksBefore` or not. If you return true here it means the condition satisfied. Otherwise, the alert is within the two weeks bracket.

```dart
    final twoWeeksBeforeAlerts = allAlerts.where((e) {
      final mapDate = DateTime.tryParse(e['date']);

      const duration = Duration(days: 14);
      final twoWeeksBefore = DateTime.now().subtract(duration);

      return mapDate?.isBefore(twoWeeksBefore) ?? false;
    }).toList();
```